# c++, do array indices need to be int?

Tags: c++, arrays

In c++, a const array, `arr`, contains 100 numbers between 0 and 80.

If I choose the numbers in `arr` to be `char`s, will they be implicitly converted to `int` everytime they are used as indices on double-pointers, i.e. `doublepointer[arr[i]]`?

Comment: Why should they be ints? Where do you get the idea that indices must be ints?

Comment: No, they just need to be of some integral type. That's for builtin arrays and pointers though, user-defined types can have any index-type the class-designer wants.

Comment: It's probably safer to define `arr` as an array of `unsigned char`. It won't matter for numbers between 0 and 80, but the implementation-defined signedness of plain `char` means that a value outside the range 0..127 will be promoted to a negative `int` value. (I'm assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`, which is almost universally true.)

Comment: Did you pick char because the maximum value is only 80? Don't. Use int for general numbers, even if they are small in practice. It saves headaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will be converted to type `int`. According to the C++ Standard "subscript operator [] is interpreted in such a way that E1[E2] is identical to *((E1)+(E2))."
And if the additive operator is used then "The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for
operands of arithmetic or enumeration type." This means that objects of type char will be converted to objects of type int when they are used in expressions as indices in the subscript operator.

Take into account that type char may behave either as unsigned char or as signed char depending on the compiler options you will select or that are set by default.

As for types that can be used as indices in the subscript operator then they shall be either unscoped enumerations or some integral types.

Comment: Yes, an index of type `char` will be converted to `int` (and it's the *value* that's converted, not any object). But that's only because of the usual arithmetic conversions. An index of type `unsigned int` or `long`, for example, is not converted to `int`. The indexing operator itself does not require an operand of any specific integer type. (That was the question in the title.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson  The title does not correspond to what was written in the post itself.

Comment: I agree. Still, I suggest addressing both in your answer.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Do you mean the point that any integral type can be used as an index?

Comment: @Keith Thompson Well if you want this so much then I will add one more line to the message.

Comment: Why must you take this personally? It's not about what I want.

Answer (score 1):

For a genuine array, the index is (converted to) some integral type, as explained in [Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25231802/841108).

But several STL containers e.g. [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) have their own `operator []` whose argument might be (e.g. for some `map`-s) a non-integral type. By convention, that operator might be related to some `at` member function.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary that you can have an int as a index of an array. You can have characters as array index but they have there own problems. Char indexes can create problems as they may be either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. If a
user-provided character is used as an array index, it's possible that
the value is negative, and in most cases, that would mean memory
outside of the array will be accessed. Hence it would result in an unnecessary chaos. Hence int is recommended and mostly used as array index

Comment: Somehow, I got the impression that the most used index-type (especially due to the standard-library) is `std::size_t`.

Comment: When indices are between 0 and 80 i think unsigned/signed doesnt matter

Comment: @Deduplicator:- Yes thats true and that is there in the C++ standard as well!

Comment: @Coolwater:- Indeed! I just tried to bring the problems which it may lead too!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title, an array index can be of any "unscoped enumeration or integral type". Array indexing is defined in terms of pointer addition; one operand must be a pointer to a completely-defined object type, and the other must be of some integral or unscoped enumeration
type.

(Note that the word "object" here has nothing to do with object-oriented programming.)

There's nothing special about type `int` in this context. When you *define* an array type or object, you don't specify the type of the index, just the element type and the number of elements. When you use an index expression `arr[i]`, the index can be of any integral type; for example `unsigned int` and `long long` are valid, and will not be implicitly converted.

To address the specific code you're asking about, `char` is an integral type, so it's perfectly valid as an array index -- but you need to be careful. The "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied to the index expression, which means that if it's of a type narrower than `int` it will be promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`. These promotions do not apply to an index whose type is already at least as wide as `int`.

If plain `char` happens to be signed in your implementation, and if the value happens to be negative, then it will be promoted to a *negative* `int` value, which is probably not what you want. In your particular case, you say the values are between 0 to 80, all of which are within the range of positive values of type `char`. But just in case your requirements change later, you'd be better off defining your array with an element type of `unsigned char`.